# Python SOCK_RAW seems to listen on all ports

Tags: python, networking

Consider the following code:

```
import socket, sys, time


HOST = '172.16.0.19'
PORT = 1000

#create a raw socket
try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
except socket.error , msg:
        print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()

s.bind((HOST,PORT))

while True:
        print "Waiting for SYN..."
        rec_packet, addr = s.recvfrom(100)
        print "Incoming connection detected!"
        print "".join(map("{0:08b}".format, map(ord, list(rec_packet[0:10]))))
        print addr[0]
        print ""
```

It is a simplified version of an automated SYN attack detector. When I use:

```
nmap 172.16.0.19 -sS -p 1001 **NOTE THE DIFFERENT PORT**
```

I still get a detection from the code. Does s.bind not listen only on given port?

SSH to the target also triggers the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A raw socket (see `raw(7)` for details) supports sending raw IP datagrams.  Raw ip datagrams *don't have ports*. Ports are a construct of higher-level protocols layered on top of IP, like UDP and TCP.

You could inspect the received packet yourself to extract the udp/tcp port.

An alternative solution might utilize the netfilter framework to capture packets on specific tcp ports that have the SYN flag set, and then send these to your program via the [nfqueue](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/using-nfqueue-and-libnetfilter_queue/) extension.

Comment: Based on my needs, I extracted the encapsulated TCP packet and extracted the port. Worked fine!